# How to access object outside the promised function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-scope

I am new in angularjs and as starter i have a problem with accessing object outside then function. I have created a factory:

```
    var injectParams = ['$http'];
    var address = function ($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.get = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/address',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                service: 'address'
            }
        });
    };
  return factory;
 }
```

And a controller method:

```
   function getAddresses() {
        address_factory.get().then(function success(response) {
            $scope.billing = response.data.billing;
            $scope.shipping = response.data.shipping;
            console.log(response.data);

        }, function error(x) {
            console.log(x);
        });
    }
   getAddresses();
```

The question is how can i access `$scope.billing` object outside `getAddresses` function? I have read promises in angularjs but i don't understand how to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.billing` is accessible everywhere in the controller and the template bound to that controller. But the value of `$scope.billing` is dynamic, it is `undefined` until the factory-get Promise is resolved. To reflect a dynamic nature of `$scope.billing` in the template you may try following approach:

```
 function getAddresses() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    address_factory.get().then(function success(response) {
      $scope.billing = response.data.billing;
      $scope.loading = false;
      $scope.error = null;
    }, function error() {
      $scope.loading = false;
      $scope.error = true;
    });
  }
 getAddresses();
```

and then in the template:

```
<div ng-if="loading">
  Loading...
</div>
<div ng-if="!loading && error">
  Got an error!
</div>
<div ng-if="!loading && !error">
  Billing: {{billing}}
</div>
```

---

Also, you may use `$scope.$watch` in the controller to watch for `$scope.billing` changes:

```
// ...
getAddresses();

$scope.$watch('billing', function() {
  // $scope.billing has been changed
  console.log($scope.billing);
});
```

But I would recommend to do all necessary logic right in the success-callback of the `Promise.then` call.

Comment: Yes ,you are right.I understood the reason why this is happening.Do you have any pattern suggestion how to fix it.'To fix it' i mean how to use necessary logic inside success-callback?

Comment: @MrAlb There is nothing to fix, this is how the Promise work, so just put your logic in the watch-callback or in the `address_factory.get` success callback (I'd prefer the second option). Also, if you are ok with ES2017, you may try [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax to make the code more synchronous-like.

Comment: Maybe im not explaining to well.I have created another pagination function in same controller.Idea is , i want to find the length of this of $scope.billing object, so i can use in the pagination function.I understood how promises works but if not find the length of this object i cant do pagination.I am sorry that i am spending your time.

Comment: @MrAlb Process the pagination only when the Promise is resolved. You may block pagination in the template via `loading` approach. And you may init your pagination logic on billing-watch callback or in `address_factory.get` success callback. If you still have problems with it, I would recommend to post a new question with more details related to pagination case.

Answer (score 2):

$scope variables are available outse the promise once everywhere in the controller...

Hence $scope.billing will be accessible in html and controller js both...

Comment: What does this mean ... 'Hence $scope.billing will be accessible in html and controller js both' ? when i try to ouput $scope.billing or to find the length  of this object outside the getAddresses function  the result is empty. console.log($scope.billing); I mean i know in the html i can access objects but want to access in the controller.

Comment: It is because the promise is in the event loop and you are accessing before the event loop returns .. try using it inside $timeout

Comment: @Danish No, **do not use `$timeout`**. Use a `then` callback on the promise to run code when the value is available.

Answer (score 0):

**$scope** means the current scope that is the current area where **some-controller.js** & the **some-view.html** is accessible.

If you set any variable to **$scope** it will be accessible anywhere in the some-controller.js & some-view.html.

Suppose you set **ng-controller** to any div as `<div ng-controller="SomeController">.....</div>`. So any thing with $scope like $scope.something is set in controller will be accessible in the controller and withing this div too, because the scope of the controller is this.